# Duration as difference betweed to Datetime fields does not respect Seconds

Tags: formula, datetime, date

It seems that Seconds are ignored in formula fields if you create the difference between Datetime/Time fields.

Say you have two Datetime fields: End__c and Start__c

Take a formula field Duration__c (in Seconds) defined as

```
(End__c - Start__c) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Assume

- End__c is "2014-08-31T18:52:**40**.000+0000"
- Start__c is "2014-08-31T18:52:**38**.000+0000"

Duration__c evaluates to 0.00 seconds but should be 2.00 seconds

Comment: It's also a challenge to enter seconds on the standard UI. See therefore http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48299/how-to-enter-seconds-into-datetime-fields-using-the-standard-ui?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the formula to include Seconds into the evaluation

```
  ( End__c - Start__c ) * 24 * 60 * 60
+ ( VALUE(MID(TEXT(End__c),18,2)) - VALUE(MID(TEXT(Start__c),18,2)) )
```

Comment: Uwe - you might want to mark this as 'solved'