# How to enter Seconds into Datetime fields using the standard UI

Tags: page-layout, datetime, fields

Say you have a datetime field Start__c on a pagelayout.

Now try to enter a date (we have DE locale enabled, but should be similar in EN):

- 31.08.2014 14:53 ==> works
- 31.08.2014 14:53:38 ==> doesn't work

The only way I found is to set it programmatically via APEX.

What is the easiest way to deal with Seconds using as much of Standard Functionality as possible?

Is there a feature to enable Seconds for Datetime? (Possibly even Milliseconds?)

The datetime field is perfectly capable of carrying Seconds in the database. However when it comes to calculations, Seconds seems again to be second-class citizens: [Duration as difference betweed to Datetime fields does not respect Seconds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48297/duration-as-difference-betweed-to-datetime-fields-does-not-respect-seconds)

Finally I come back to Milliseconds:

Is the best we can do to track them in a separate field like StartMilliseconds__c (number) in addition to Start__c (datetime)?

Comment: The funny side of this is when you use a default value with seconds for the datetime field (like this  `DATETIMEVALUE("2013-11-15 12:11:10")`), then you will see this default datetime on the standard page without seconds. But after save it saves with default seconds! What is going on here? :)

Comment: @mast0r **there is magic going on!** Under the hood, there are seconds. My guess is, that they have been _silenced_ somehow, because in most CRM-use-cases they do more bother than benefit. But on the platform we don't have only CRM-use-cases and Seconds may become a crucial piece of information. Cool would be a DatetimeEx field type with Milliseconds and proper Math inside formulas. Anyone push this on IdeaExchange already?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp provide by the standard UI  have only hh:mm notation in the date time So to get seconds also  You would have to go for a custom field in case you want to show your time in HH:MM:SS