# Date format compatibility

Tags: apex, custom-field, datetime

I have received a datetime format not supported to load in salesforce. Can someone suggest a way out here.

Format received:

```
29-JUL-13 01.17.05.335000000 PM
```

SFDC supported Format:

```
2014-08-18T19:27:16.000Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not mention if you are looking for a solution for dataloader, a formula or a piece of apex code to convert the date.

So I assume you want to use apex since you have tagged the question with apex.

As of my knowledge, there is no "one-liner" to do it. I'll try to push you on the right track, but won't provide full code - but it's easy to write it.

- Use this function to initialize your Datetime object:  **Datetime.newInstance**(Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer) : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_Datetime_newInstance_4.htm
- to get the right parameters use **string instance methods** to cut out the appropriate parts from your input string : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_instance_methods.htm
- for the **month**: cut the three letters in string and use a couple of if() to translate to integer
- for the numeric text parts use **Integer.valueOf**() to convert
- for PM use an if() and add 12 to the hours-integer. Or try the ? operator which is much more fun.

There are a few things which might give you not a perfect solution:

- Salesforce supports no Milliseconds for Datetime. Probably you just accept to loose this precision or you may use an separate field for it
- Seconds are somehow half-supported. You can write them properly with apex, but the UI doesn't handle them very well
- I spend some time yesterday on these challenges

  - [Duration as difference betweed to Datetime fields does not respect Seconds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48297/duration-as-difference-betweed-to-datetime-fields-does-not-respect-seconds)
  - [How to enter Seconds into Datetime fields using the standard UI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48299/how-to-enter-seconds-into-datetime-fields-using-the-standard-ui)

**Bottomline:**

if you don't care about Seconds and Milliseconds, it's very easy and straight forward. If you just want to store Seconds but not Edit them using the Standard UI, it's also no problem.

Comment: Hi Uwe! Yes I do my loading by dataloader.

Comment: for dataloader you could do something like the above but in Excel. Or - if you do any kind of import jobs more frequently - you could decide not to use dataloader and have a look at tools like TalenD: https://de.talend.com/ - there again, you will write a couple of lines to convert the string

Comment: I updated my answer because I suggested by accident the GMT version of datetime.newInstance() - but btw keep also timezones in mind, if necessary.