# DateTime: was there a (silent) change in the math for DateTime calculations in formulas?

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime

In Summer'14 (likely also in Winter'14) there was a very special behavior of the platform to deal with precise datetime calculations as described here: [Duration as difference betweed to Datetime fields does not respect Seconds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48297/duration-as-difference-betweed-to-datetime-fields-does-not-respect-seconds)

It ends up that seconds has been disrespected by the platform, so that a formula field Duration__c (in Seconds) defined as

```
(End__c - Start__c) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

with

- End__c is "2014-08-31T18:52:**40**.000+0000"
- Start__c is "2014-08-31T18:52:**38**.000+0000"

has had evaluated to 0.00 seconds but should have be 2.00 seconds

I have considered this as a bug. (Since we have no premier support, we were never able to interact about this issue with the salesforce support)

At this time, I found a workaround like that:

```
  ( End__c - Start__c ) * 24 * 60 * 60
+ ( VALUE(MID(TEXT(End__c),18,2)) - VALUE(MID(TEXT(Start__c),18,2)) )
```

But **today**, this seems to be changed (or fixed if you like). I noticed that because all my calculations with the workaround above are counting the seconds **twice**. Mmmmm.....

My question is: is that change somewhere documented? E. g. somewhere in the release notes? Is there any good way to be notified in such cases were we find a bug as mere non-premier customers, spend hours to fix it with workarounds and than run into an error, when salesforce has taken actions to fix it on their end so that as a result our workaround turns into a bug?